# How to make a question, with an integer in it, asked again when it is left blank

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and I am not sure how to make a question involving an integer asked again when an invalid character is entered or it is left blank. Could someone please help me.

I have only tried what I know and nothing has really worked.

```
# Asks for age
age = int(input("Please enter your age: "))
# Prevents age from being left blank
# I need help with this part
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input("Please enter your age: "))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    break
```

This runs in a loop until you get a valid value

Comment: This does not check for negative integers.